# custom sorting for find command output

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to get sorted directory/file list with unix "find" command.

```
# find . -type f 
.
./bin
./data
./data/disks
./inc
./inc/calls
./inc/calls/show
./inc/calls/show/system
./inc/calls/show/cli
./inc/calls/show/network
./inc/calls/show/stats
./inc/calls/services
./inc/calls/services/ntp
./inc/calls/services/tsa
./inc/calls/services/webgui
./inc/calls/services/engine
./inc/calls/system
./inc/calls/change
./inc/calls/change/password
./inc/calls/change/network
./inc/calls/disk
./inc/calls/disk/encr
./inc/etc
```

I want to sort it like:

```
./inc/calls/show/system \    
./inc/calls/show/cli \
./inc/calls/show/network \
./inc/calls/show/stats \
./inc/calls/services/ntp \
./inc/calls/services/tsa \
./inc/calls/services/webgui \
./inc/calls/services/engine \
./inc/calls/change/password \
./inc/calls/change/network \
./inc/calls/disk/encr \
./inc/calls/system \
./inc/calls/change \
./inc/calls/services \
./inc/calls/disk \
./inc/calls/show \
./inc/calls \
./data/disks \
./inc/etc \
./bin \
./data \
./inc
```

Which node (directory/file) has more child (directory/files) should be first... i want to do it with bash or python... What is the best way to do that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match lines containing `/` and prepend the number of fields to the line using `/` as the separator, sort on the numbers of fields and remove the count.

```
$ awk -F/ '/\//{print NF,$0}' file | sort -nrk1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
./inc/calls/show/system
./inc/calls/show/stats
./inc/calls/show/network
./inc/calls/show/cli
./inc/calls/services/webgui
./inc/calls/services/tsa
./inc/calls/services/ntp
./inc/calls/services/engine
./inc/calls/disk/encr
./inc/calls/change/password
./inc/calls/change/network
./inc/calls/system
./inc/calls/show
./inc/calls/services
./inc/calls/disk
./inc/calls/change
./inc/etc
./inc/calls
./data/disks
./inc
./data
./bin
```

Comment: The OP says: "Which node (directory/file) has more child (directory/files) should be first...". You're listing the deepest path first. If a file was added to "inc/calls/services", it should be listed first, but won't be with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use python and try to convert:

```
a/b
a/c
b/e/f
b/e/g
```

in something like:

```
{'a': {'b': {}, 'c': {}},
'b': {'e': {'f': {}, 'g': {}}},
}
```

To achieve this:

```
def add_list_to_dict(lst,d):
   key, lst = lst[0], lst[1:]
   if not key in d:
       d[key] = {}
   if lst:
       add_list_to_dict(lst,d[key])

d = {}
for path in paths:
    add_list_to_dict(path.split('/'),d)
```